# Spring data JPA consumes all the connection objects

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I have a scenario where in data is uploaded from excel sheet to mysql db. I am using spring data jpa. And the service calls the entities recursively after stuffing them with data taken from excel sheet to save in db. This creates "unable to acquire jdbc connections" after a certain load.

I tried with @Transactional to know advantage. Then I am thinking of using EntityManager manually in code and control transaction boundary so that all recursive save calls of entities happen within one transaction and thereby one connection object. I just wanted to check would it be a nice idea or is there any other approach I should take which is more performant. Needless to say anyhow I have to do it through entities.

Comment: Can you show your code? which MYSQL enigne are you using? How much data could be in excel?

Comment: In addition to that can you also update the question with the following requirement clarification. If excel contains 10 000 records, if the application errors after 9 000 records, 1) Do you want those 9 000 successful records in the database or 2) You don't want any record saved in database, if the insertion fails half way through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is completely based on the assumption that the way of implementing the requirement is faulty as there isn't any code shared in the question.

By your approach, yes you will run out of the connection as the entity population would surely be much faster than persisting that entity in the database and since you are doing it recursively your application will run out connections at one point of time if the amount of the data is very high, numbers are certainly a factor here.

The other approach I would prefer is that you can prepare your entities(Assuming all the data is for a common entity class) and store in a collection, once it is ready you can persist all of it in one transaction using saveAll() method.
If the data is not for common entities you can create multiple lists of different entities and initiate the DB operations after processing the excel sheet.

Comment: Yah.. You are quite correct. The code is invoking save recursively and that should be refactored to invoke saveAll. But just wondering if I call the same save method recursively in a transaction boundary created from EntityManager object, will that solve the issue "unable to acquire jdbc connection" issue.

My question is when a transaction is opened and closed manually, all the entities saved inside that boundary does happen over a single connection object or it spreads over multiple connection objects?

Comment: Your question is pretty valid but even though you will be doing this whole operation within a single transaction you are accessing the db multiple times and each time your application will be using new connection from the connection pool and that is what happened in your case.